# Access a mount drive via terminal (mounted via samba)

Tags: mount, samba, drive, sharing

I have trouble accessing a mounted drive in Ubuntu via terminal. I can access it via the address bar using the address

```
smb://UNCLE;username@server/home_staff/username
```

But I can't access it via the terminal

Comment: If you have mounted it under /home, try mounting it somewhere else (eg. /staff).  *Directories under /home may be mounted, but can be shadowed*  Providing your actual `mount` command may help us provide more clues.

Comment: I don't remember how they are mounted or where they are mounted. I have tried [cd /dev/sdax] command it did not work

Comment: @AmanMittal .. Yyou can't cd to at disk device. It must be mounted somewhere, and the cd must go to that place.

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal and run:

```
ls -al /run/user/$UID/gvfs
```

You should see a list of all the shares you mounted through Nautilus.

They look like you would need to put quotes around them when running commands on them but they do not. So if I wanted to get a list of the files in the mount point I would run something like this:

```
ls -al /run/user/$UID/gvfs/smb-share:server=server-name,share=share-name
```

Comment: The only solution that worked for me was this one. first I created a mount point    `sudo mkdir /media/username`   then   mounted the share folder to the mount point  `sudo mount -t cifs -o username=username //servername/home_staff/username  /media/username`

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work anymore on Ubuntu 22. I have SMB shares mounted by my gvfs directory is empty.